# MYSQL Count(Distinct) Group By

Tags: mysql

This select keeps timing out:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `invoices`) 
FROM `data` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
GROUP BY `store`
```

I have made indexes on invoices, date, store and invoices, store, date. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you aggregating by `store` but not including it in the `select`?

Comment: This was the problem as well as creating a temporary table like @Marcx 's query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SELECT `store`, COUNT(*) FROM 
   (SELECT `store`, `invoices`
          FROM `data` 
         WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
       GROUP BY `store`, `invoices`
   ) tbl
GROUP BY `store`
```

Here's a fiddle, without the `date` column and check...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb83c/5/0

Comment: Thank you, the temp table really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I think you are working with a big table. I solved it by changing some values in configuration file:

```
key_buffer = 128M
thread_stack = 128K
thread_cache_size = 8
table_cache = 8192
max_heap_table_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 512M

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G 

innodb_log_file_size = 512M
skip_name_resolve

join_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

key_buffer_size         = 64M
sort_buffer_size        = 1M
tmp_table_size          = 256M
max_heap_table_size     = 512M
read_buffer_size        = 64K
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 64K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
```

But these values are changing according to your pc and work. I suggest you to make some search about "mysql configuration for big data". You will find some information about their meanings. By the way you should also have a primary key in your table. I think it also affects the performance. Finally you should check the preferences in mysql. You may need to increase the mysql session settings under the sql editor section. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT store, COUNT(DISTINCT invoices) 
FROM data 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
GROUP BY store
```